# How do I check if a function returns a regular value or calls error?

Tags: function, haskell, error-handling

I got some code like:

```
setA :: Integer -> Integer
setA 3 = 5
setA 5 = 6
setA 7 = error "some error one"
setA _ = error "some error two"
```

now I try to write another function

```
checkError :: Integer -> Bool
checkError x = if HERE_TO_CHECK_IF setA x RETURNS some error two
                then False
                else True
```

but how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: What did you want to do using `checkError`? What are you supposed to use `setA` for? Maybe there's a way of doing what you need, but we don't know the big picture.

Comment: Whitebox checking, `checkError x = even x || x < 3 || x > 7` is forbidden?

Comment: nop @DanielFischer :) I did something like this, but the Integers are different, the complete function also. I was not allowed to post the same functions, maybe our profs are searchin everwhere if we used some other codes ;) i really have rewritten my version.. Now it is working..

Answer (score 7):

As said already in the other answers, you should avoid using `error` and instead use

```
setA :: Integer -> Either String Integer
setA 3 = Right 5
setA 5 = Right 6
setA 7 = Left "some error one"
setA _ = Left "some error two"

checkError :: Either String Integer -> Bool
checkError (Left _)  = False
checkError (Right _) = True
```

But if you can't do this, look at [the source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/spoon/0.3/doc/html/src/Control-Spoon.html) to the [spoon package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon) to see how to do what your professor is asking for. It's icky.

Then you can say

```
checkError :: Integer -> Bool
checkError x = case teaspoon x of
    Nothing -> False
    Just _  -> True
```

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, the `error` call is not meant to be caught by the caller – if you want the error to be recoverable, the `setA` function should use some other mechanism (like `Either`). If you insist on catching the `error`, you may do so inside the IO monad, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243117/how-to-catch-and-ignore-a-call-to-the-error-function).

Comment: but we are not allowed to change setA, but i need a function which checks, if x is 3,5,7 (only not the second error is allowed in setA, everything else shoudl return true)

Comment: Did you read the linked question, especially the answer about `Control.Exception` and `spoon`?

Answer (score 2):

Your `setA` function is incorrect. If you expect a function to be able to return erroneous values, you should use `Either`:

```
setA :: Integer -> Either String Integer
setA 3 = Right 5
setA 5 = Right 6
setA 7 = Left "some error one"
setA _ = Left "some error two"
```

Checking for the error is trivial:

```
checkError :: Either String Integer -> Bool
checkError = either (const True) (const False)
```

Comment: i am not able to change setA, this is set by default (at university we are not allowed to change setA, only the other one :))

Comment: @ahmet2106 You can tell your professor to go ... check his qualification then. [This question will explain why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243117/how-to-catch-and-ignore-a-call-to-the-error-function).

Comment: I think the requirement might be sensible. After the students are through the pain of catching the error in the IO monad you can say that this method of error handling is obviously too cumbersome and come up with a better interface.

Answer (score 1):

Although `error` should only be used for [unrecoverable bad state](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Error_vs._Exception) (so no need to be catched), here is an exact example that catches error calls

but I think that this is not the way except for writing debuggers:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Prelude hiding (catch)
import Control.Exception

setA :: Integer -> Integer
setA 3 = 5
setA 5 = 6
setA 7 = error "some error one"
setA _ = error "some error two"

main = do
  (print $ setA 9)
  `catch` (\(ErrorCall msg) -> putStrLn $ "I caught you, ErrorCall: " ++ msg)
  `catch` (\(exc::SomeException) -> putStrLn $ "Other exception: " ++ show exc)
```

For normal programming, wrap possible erroneous results with the type `Either`, as the other answers explain.